# bash using "find" in dir1 and delete these files in dir2

Tags: bash, find

I have two folders. I want to find files with a specific extension recursively in dir1 and delete files which are found in dir1 from dir2. I think this can be done with -exec command in find. Deleting it from dir1 is quite simple - but how can this be done for dir2?

find /home/admin/.cache/yay/ -name '*.pkg.tar.zst' -exec basename {} ; (now remove the found files in /tmp/test/)

Comment: dir1 has subdirectories. Problem is that -exec gets full path to file and I want to delete files with the same name in different folder... The files in dir2 are not in subdirectories of dir2

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer that works best for you. Since you've never accepted any answer to your questions you may want to look back and accept those too. You do this with the tick mark ✓ alongside the answer. This is how you say "thankyou" here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the file paths from dir1. Strip back the path to just the filename. Delete each found file from dir2:

```
find /home/admin/.cache/yay/ -type f -name '*.pkg.tar.zst' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo rm -f -- "/path/to/dir2/${f##*/}"; done' _ {} +
```

If you don't want the shell loop,

```
find /home/admin/.cache/yay/ -type f -name '*.pkg.tar.zst' -exec sh -c 'echo rm -f -- "/path/to/dir2/${1##*/}"' _ {} \;
```

Remove `echo` when you're satisfied it's going to work as you expect

Answer (score 1):

Seems easier with `xargs`:

```
(cd dir1 && find . -name '*.ext' ! -type d -print0) |
  (cd dir2 && xargs -r0 rm -f --)
```

For each `foo.ext` and `subdir/bar.ext` in `dir1` would delete the same `foo.ext` and `subdir/bar.ext` in `dir2`.

If you want to delete the files by the same name even if they're not found in the same directories in `dir1` and `dir2` (for instance in the example above, remove all of `dir2/bar.ext`, `dir2/any/level/of/subdirectory/foo.ext`) with `zsh`:

```
typeset -U names
names=( dir1/**/*.ext(ND^/:t) )
rm -f -- dir2/**/(${(~j[|])names})(D^/)
```

- `typeset -U names` gives the *unique* attribute to the variable, so that when assigned as an array, the elements are unique (deduplicated).
- `**/` any level (including 0) of subdirectories
- `N`: `N`ullglob: does not complain if there's no match. Actually, you migh as will leave it off for the shell to abort if doesn't find any `.ext` file.
- `D`: `D`otglob: doesn't skip hidden files.
- `^/` is like `find`'s `! -type d` to exclude the files of type *directory* (which can't be removed without  first deleting their contents).
- `:t`:  gets the `t`ail, the base name
- `${(j[string])array}` joins the elements of the array with `string` in-between. With `~`, the joining string is treated as a glob operator, so we end up with a `(foo.ext|bar.ext|...)` glob.

Same golfed on one command using an anonymous function (and the `u` parameter expansion flag in place of `typeset -U`):

```
(){rm -f dir2/**/(${(~j[|])${(u)@}})(D^/)} dir1/**/*.ext(D^/:t)
```

Another approach that would be more efficient if there's a very large number of different names is to use an associative array:

```
typeset -A to_remove
: dir1/**/*.ext(ND^/e['to_remove[$REPLY:t]=1'])
rm -f -- dir2/**/*.ext(De['(( $to_remove[$REPLY:t] ))']^/)
```

If you just want to delete them at the root of `dir2` (in the example above, remove `dir2/foo.ext` and `dir2/bar.ext` only, not those in subdirectories), remove the `**/` in the `rm` commands above or with GNU `find` and `sort`:

```
(cd dir1 && find . -name '*.ext' -printf '%f\0') |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  (cd dir2 && xargs -r0 rm -f --)
```